# Factory method does not work when used in dynamic library with templated classes

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have created a templated class where I would like to use the factory method. The templates should be explicitly defined to create objects of type `int`, `double` and `bool`.

The factory has a checkIn registry mechanism through the use of the a `static bool`.

The factory is defined as:

```
#ifndef Factory_H
#define Factory_H

#include <memory> 
#include <map>

template<class Type> 
class Base;

template<class Type> 
class Factory
{
    public:
        using createObj = std::shared_ptr<Base<Type>>(*)();

        static bool registerObj( const std::string& name, createObj type)
        {
            std::map< std::string, Factory::createObj >& registry = getRegistry();

            if(registry.find(name) == registry.end())
            { 
                registry[name] = type;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };

        static std::shared_ptr<Base<Type>> New( const std::string& name)
        {
            auto it = getRegistry().find(name);
            if (it == getRegistry().end()) {
                return nullptr;
            }
            return it->second();
        };
        
    private:
        static std::map<std::string, createObj>& getRegistry()
        {
            static std::map<std::string, Factory::createObj> registry;
            return registry;
        };        
};

#endif
```

The base class is defined as:

```
#ifndef Base_H
#define Base_H

#include "factory.h"

template<class Type>
class Base: public Factory<Type>
{
    public:
        Base();
        virtual void foo() = 0;
};

#endif
```

and implemented as:

```
#include "Base.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class Type>
Base<Type>::Base()
{}

// Explicit initalization
template class Base<int>;
template class Base<double>;
template class Base<bool>;
```

The derived class is defined as:

```
#ifndef Derived_H
#define Derived_H

#include "Base.h"

template<class Type>
class Derived: public Base<Type>
{
    private:
        static bool checkIn_;
        static std::string className_;

    public:
        Derived();
        virtual void foo() ;
        static std::shared_ptr<Base<Type>> Create();

};
#endif
```

and implemented as:

```
#include "Derived.h"

template<class Type>
Derived<Type>::Derived()
{}

template<class Type>
std::string Derived<Type>::className_("Derived");

template<class Type>
std::shared_ptr<Base<Type>> Derived<Type>::Create()
{
    return std::make_shared<Derived>();
}


template<class Type>
bool Derived<Type>::checkIn_ = Base<Type>::registerObj(Derived::className_, Derived::Create);

template<class Type>
void Derived<Type>::foo()
{
    std::cout << typeid(Type).name() << std::endl;
}

// Explicit initalization
template class Derived<int>;
template class Derived<double>;
template class Derived<bool>;
```

The main.cpp is defined as:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Derived.h"
#include "Base.h"

int main()
{
    auto obj1 = Base<int>::New("Derived");
    auto obj2 = Base<double>::New("Derived");
    auto obj3 = Base<bool>::New("Derived");

    obj1->foo();
    obj2->foo();
    obj3->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

@ Edited

If I compile everything in one executable: `g++ -g *.cpp -o main`. The factory method works.

If I try to compile it as a library; `g++ -g -fPIC Base.cpp Derived.cpp -shared -o test.so` followed by `g++ -g -o main main.cpp -I . -L. test.so` it no longer works, I get a `segmentation fault`. There is nothing in the registry... I would guess the `static bool` is not doing its job.

How can I make this work?

In the scope of the project, I would like to have a library that is able to use the factory method for `int`, `double` and `bool` that all share the same interface. They will differ in a `std::vector<Type>` attribute which will store some data. In case the `factory method` is not the best design which alternatives are best?

Best Regards

Comment: *it no longer works* How do you know it? Do you get errors? Which errors?

Comment: BTW explicitly instantiated templates are not used in .so, thus are not exported by a linker.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/7976805), OP uses explicit instantiations. Altough I agree that the question is missing description of that exactly is wrong to make it [mcve].

Comment: Hello to all, and thanks for the input. I think the provided code in the question should be a minimal reproducible example. In fact even the compilation flags to reproduce the problem have been given.
@273K The code gives a `segmentation fault` because there is no class registered [this is problem!]. In the scope of my code, the factory method should be used for the indicated types `int` `double` and `bool`.  Instead of creating 3 classes with 3 factory methods  I thought I could make it a templated class and let the compiler do the rest with the explicit instanciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ldd main
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeec319000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fefe98c2000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fefe98a2000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fefe967a000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fefe9593000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fefe9b18000)
```

Your executable doesn't even know `test.so` exists, it doesn't reference anything from there so the shared library is simply ignored. No wonder `registerObj` is not called.

Compile with

```
g++ -g -o main main.cpp -I . -L. -Wl,--no-as-needed test.so -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-rpath=.
```

Another way to achieve the same goal is moving the definition of `Factory::New` to a new `Factory.cpp` file, and explicitly instantiating with only the types needed. This way `main` references symbols defined in `test.so` and no special linker flags are needed. This also makes an attempt to call say `Base<char>::New` a link-time error, rather than a run-time error.

Comment: This worked! Even without the `static_cast<void>(&Derived<int>::checkIn_);`.  So it was a linking error... Would you be so kind as to explain the flags? The `ldd` comamnd is very welcome! If I comment out one of the available types, say `bool`. It still allows the construction and compilation [altough this will produce a `segmentation fault`]. Anyway to give an error if a type other than the explicit template types is used?

Comment: `man ld` should provide info on ld flags. If you want to error out on invalid types, mobe `Factory::New` definition to a .cpp file and explicitly instantiate only those types you need --- and then you won't need special ld flags.

Comment: This solved everything! Thanks!

Comment: Just for completeness can you tell how it can be compiled after putting the `New` method in a `.cpp` file. I did that but still can only link the library with the commands you provided: `g++ -g -o main main.cpp -I . -L. -Wl,--no-as-needed test.so -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-rpath=.` which flags can be dropped ?

Comment: Works for me. You need to explicitly instantiate `New` (using `template ...` and not `template <> ...` syntax). Please ask a separate question if there is any problem with it.

Comment: Oh... "I was doing `template class Factory<int>;` `template class Factory<double>;`

Comment: I will post a follow up question.

Comment: You can use the same link command you used originally

Comment: I have place a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76090929/factory-method-in-dynamic-library-with-explicitly-instantiated-templated-classes. Would you be so kind as to check if the implementation of `Factory.cpp` is as you described?